# Failed - Starting emulator for AVD 'VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2017

Using vs2107 v15.3.3, I did lunch the android emulator and get the following error message. How Can I fix that error ?

Starting emulator for AVD 'VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone'
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

**adb_server_notify: Failed to establish connection to ADB server
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-555**

[image]

Comment: Yesterday I was able to run temporary the demo. But after couple minutes letting the apps and the emulator on idle both did freeze. Also trying to restart the ADB sever from VS2017 did not work.  Is it possible that my computer is the cause of the problem. here is the configuration. I have an Intel core 2 quad with 8G ram (DDR2) and a hard disk SSD type 240G. Additional info When I did build the apps, 75% of memory is used.  The emulator use appx 25% of the CPU. I also notice that the ADB process look doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-14-Upgrading-Android-Support-Libraries?term=xamarin) did help me to solve the issue and get the emulator and VS2017 more stable. I did match the target android version in project properties with the version stated in the "packages.config" and create an emulator at the same API version. So far so good. It does work now.